# Java error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bindin server run class

Tags: java, sockets, io, client-server, ports

When I run the client program I get this error. I checked to see if the port number is being used and already tried changing the port multiple times.

the server uses three classes:

the main and gui

```
class ServerGui extends Server implements ActionListener
{
public ServerGui() throws Exception
{
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Check in Desk");
    jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jfrm.setSize(500, 500);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);
    //menu bar
    JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu jmView = new JMenu("View");
    // items
    JMenu jmEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
    // items
    JMenu jmHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    // items
    jmb.add(jmView);
    jmb.add(jmEdit);
    jmb.add(jmHelp);
    //add menuBar
    jfrm.setJMenuBar(jmb);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    String comString = ae.getActionCommand();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run()
            {                 
                try{
                    new ServerGui();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e + "damn");
                }
            }
        });
}
}
```

The server class

```
public class Server extends Thread
{

public Server() throws IOException
{               
    this.start();       
}

public void run()
{     
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            ServerSocket socketOnWhichToListenForClients= new ServerSocket(9876);  
            Socket socketBackToClient = socketOnWhichToListenForClients.accept();
            new ClientHandler(socketBackToClient);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e + "in server run class");
    }
}

}
```

client handler

```
public class ClientHandler extends Thread
{
private Socket socketBackToClient;
public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
{
    socketBackToClient = socket;
    this.start();
}
public void run()
{
    try
    {
       InputStream is = socketBackToClient.getInputStream();
       BufferedReader message = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
       String input = message.readLine();
       System.out.println(input);
       socketBackToClient.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
}
```

The client gui

```
public class ClientGui extends Client implements ActionListener
{
//private String name = "";
public ClientGui() throws Exception
{
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name.");
    if(name.equals("")) 
        return;  
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Check in Desk");
    jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jfrm.setSize(300, 170);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);
    jfrm.setResizable(false);
    //buttons
    Font font1 = new Font("SansSerif",Font.PLAIN, 24);
    Font font2 = new Font("SansSerif",Font.PLAIN, 20);

    JButton jb1 = new JButton("Help");
    jb1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    jfrm.add(jb1);
    JButton jb2 = new JButton("Check In");
    jb2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 100));
    jfrm.add(jb2);

    jb1.setFont(font1);
    jb2.setFont(font2);
    //menu bar
    JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu jmTools = new JMenu("Tools");
    JMenuItem jmiName = new JMenuItem("Name");
    JMenuItem jmiIP = new JMenuItem("Your IP");
    jmTools.add(jmiName);
    jmTools.add(jmiIP);
    // items
    JMenu jmEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
    // items
    JMenu jmHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    JMenuItem jmiAbout = new JMenuItem("About");
    jmHelp.add(jmiAbout);
    // items
    jmb.add(jmTools);
    jmb.add(jmEdit);
    jmb.add(jmHelp);
    //add menuBar
    jfrm.setJMenuBar(jmb);

    jmiName.addActionListener(this);
    jmiIP.addActionListener(this);
    jb1.addActionListener(this);
    jb2.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    String confirmHelp = "";
    String confirmCheckIn = "";
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Name"))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your name is " + getClientName());
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Your IP"))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your IP is " + getIpAddress());
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Help"))
    {
        confirmHelp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are You Sure You Want Help?");
        if(confirmHelp != null && confirmHelp.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            Help();
        }
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Check In"))
    {
    confirmCheckIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are You Sure You Want To Check       In?");
        if(confirmCheckIn != null && confirmCheckIn.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            CheckIn();
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run()
            {

                try{
                    new ClientGui();
                    Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9876);              //new Client(); // add constructor with name or pc numb
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("client closed");
                }
            }
        });
}
}
```

The client

```
public class Client
{
public String name = "";
Socket clientSocket;
public Client() throws Exception
{

    try
    {
       // clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9);
        OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(os, true);
        pwrite.print("yolo");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //System.out.println("Error cant connect");   add later
    }
}


public void Help()
{
    System.out.println("you pressed help");
}

public void CheckIn()
{
    System.out.println("you pressed Check In");
}

public String getIpAddress()
{
    String str = "";
    try{
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        str = ip.toString();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.out.println("can not find IP address");
    }

    return str;
}

public String getClientName()
{
    return name;
}

}
```

Comment: Kill the Java process that is already running on that port. Alternatively try using another port.

Comment: That simply means that another process (possibly java, but could be anything) is already listening on that port. In linux you can use netstat to find the pid of the process listening on the port.

Comment: We don't need the client GUI. Don't post irrelevant code. It's a network problem, not a GUI problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at below lines where same port is used in loop to create `ServerSocket` that results into below exception.

```
try {
    while (true) {
        ServerSocket socketOnWhichToListenForClients = new ServerSocket(9876);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e + "in server run class");
}
```

Look at at the exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bindin server run class
```

---

**Don't** forget to close the `ServerSocket` in the end. Use `finally` block to close it.

Comment: thanks this seemed get rid of the error. also is there a way to mark an answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you keep recreating the ServerSocket inside the while loop. Create it once, before the loop.

Comment: @Braj For a claim of priority to succeed, the prior post would have to contain everything that this one does. Yours doesn't. In any case, priority isn't significant in StackOverflow, unless you're suggesting I copied your answer, which is demonstrably false.